# Can I define an alias in the inner query and pass on to the outer query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, alias

Since the inner query executes first, I thought I could just define an alias for the table and pass it on to the outer query if it's the very same table. So I tried the below.

```sql
SELECT
  station_id,
  num_bikes_available,
  (SELECT
     AVG(num_bikes_available)
   FROM
     bigquery-public-data.new_yourk.citibike_stations AS stations
  ) AS avg_num_bikes_avlb
FROM
  stations
```

Unfortunately it won't recognize the alias `stations`. **Is there a way to avoid typing table names repetitively in this case?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The right way to do what you want uses a window function:

```
SELECT station_id, num_bikes_available,
       AVG(num_bikes_available) OVER () AS avg_num_bikes_avlb
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_yourk.citibike_stations` stations;
```

A table alias represents a particular *instance* of a table reference.  It cannot be used as another instance of reading the table.  In any case, a correlated subquery is unnecessary and more expensive.  The window function is the best method for this calculation.